# VNC becomes view-only if OBS Studio is running

Tags: 22.04, vnc

I am having [problem](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-remote-desktop/-/issues/169) using the builtin VNC Server on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNOME Version 42.9 X11 Windowing System).

1. Settings > Sharing > Remote Desktop
2. Enable Remote Desktop
3. Enable Legacy VNC Protocol
4. Enable Remote Control
5. Change User Name & Password
6. Install [Allow Locked Remote Desktop](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4338/allow-locked-remote-desktop/) extension
7. VNC works & can control remotely
8. Open [OBS Studio](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio) v29.1.3 (installed via [official PPA](https://obsproject.com/download))
9. ***VNC session*** becomes view-only. *Remote Desktop* session still can control remotely.

I am remoting from macOS' Screen Sharing app.